# correct way to return a function's value in a method

Tags: php

I'm having some troubles getting a method to work properly, right now I have a script that determine the user's privileges, then displays the page (main.php), and inside this main.php I check the privileges and display something different regarding if the user has or not the necessary privileges.

Here is a condensended version of my functions.php with the concerned methods/functions :

```
<?php

class gator {

    public function init() {

        // get user's privileges
        $this->checkPrivileges($getprivileges);

        include("header.php");
        include("main.php");
        include("footer.php");

    }

    public function checkPrivileges($getprivileges) {
        $directory = $_SESSION['cwd'];                  // current directory
        $user = $_SESSION['simple_auth']['username'];   // get username
        $repository = gatorconf::get('repository');     // get base repertory of the file manager
        $userdir = $repository.DS.'user'.DS.$user;      // user's repertory


        if ((gator::checkPermissions('rw')) || ($userdir == $directory && gator::checkPermissions('rp'))) {
                return true;
        }

        $getprivileges = $this->scanDirectory($userdir, $directory);   // user's privileges
        return $getprivileges;

    }

    private function scanDirectory($userdir = '', $directory) {
        $folders = glob($userdir . '/*' , GLOB_ONLYDIR);
        foreach($folders as $folder){
            if (($folder == $directory && gator::checkPermissions('rp')) || (gator::checkPermissions('rw')) || ($userdir == $directory && gator::checkPermissions('rp'))) {
                return true;
            }

            if($this->scanDirectory($folder, $directory) === true) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;

        scanDirectory($userdir, $directory);
    }

}

?>
```

and here is an exemple of the code I use to check the user's privileges inside the main.php page :

```
<?php
    if (gator::checkPrivileges($getprivileges) == true) {
        echo "privileges granted";
    }
    else {
        echo "you don't have the privileges";
    }
?>
```

My problem is that my `checkPrivileges()` method is only working if the first condition is met and `true` is returned. If it's not it seems like it does not return anything, and my script stops being executed at some point most likely on the main.php page when I use `if (gator::checkPrivileges($getprivileges) == true)` (I'm not entirely sure since I'm not getting any error message).

Anyways it really looks like there is something wrong going on with my method, I'm not very experienced in php but so far after testing several things it looks like it may come from :

```
$getprivileges = $this->scanDirectory($userdir, $directory);   // user's privileges
        return $getprivileges;
```

maybe it cannot call the scanDirectory, or the value cannot be returned, or something else, I'm completely stuck :/

If anyone has a solution for this or suggestions regarding my code, I would really appreciate.

Thank you !

**update :**

I used `error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE); ini_set('display_errors', '1');` and here are the results (2 errors) :

> Strict standards: Non-static method gator::checkPrivileges() should
>   not be called statically in ... main.php on line 34

```
if (gator::checkPrivileges($getprivileges) == true) {
```

and

> Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in ...
>   functions.php on line 97

```
$getprivileges = $this->scanDirectory($userdir, $directory);   // user's privileges
```

Both theses lines are included in the original post.

**solution :**

I changed both function to a static state, and modified the way I call my scanDirectory function inside the checkPrivileges method.

```
public static function checkPrivileges($getprivileges = false) {

    $directory = $_SESSION['cwd'];                  // current directory
    $user = $_SESSION['simple_auth']['username'];   // get username
    $repository = gatorconf::get('repository');     // get base repertory of the file manager
    $userdir = $repository.DS.'user'.DS.$user;      // user's repertory

    if ($userdir == $directory && gator::checkPermissions('rp')) {
        return true;
    }

    $getprivileges = gator::scanDirectory($userdir, $directory);   // user's privileges
    return $getprivileges;

}

private static function scanDirectory($userdir = '', $directory) {

    $folders = glob($userdir . '/*' , GLOB_ONLYDIR);
    foreach($folders as $folder){
        if (($folder == $directory && gator::checkPermissions('rp')) || (gator::checkPermissions('rw')) || ($userdir == $directory && gator::checkPermissions('rp'))) {
            return true;
        }

        if(gator::scanDirectory($folder, $directory) === true) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;

}
```

Comment: Can you add `checkPermissions()` to your question?  If that's calling `checkPrivileges()` you've got yourself in an infinite loop.  -- Also you have scanDirectory() calling itself, which may be causing an infinite recursion as well.

Comment: Looks like your mixing static and non-static methods. Is `gator` supposed to be static class? `$getprivileges` looks undefined in `init()` and isn't used in `checkPrivileges()`.

Comment: The problem really is on the line you indicated. In `main.php` you call the method `checkPrivileges()` in a static context (`gator::checkPrivileges($getprivileges)`) but the method is not static and it expects `$this` to be set (it calls `$this->scanDirectory()`). Put `error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE); ini_set('display_errors', '1');` on top of your script to get the errors displayed on screen.

Comment: I think before going any further you should look at some tutorials on OOP in PHP and clean up your class structure a bit.

Comment: no checkPermissions() isn't calling checkPrivileges() at all, actually the scanDirectory recursive function is supposed to work (I tested it a lot), but if you still need checkPermissions() I'll add it, @dan08 I didn't even know class could be static or not, this is how wide my knowledges in php are :s Can you be a bit more specific ? I also have this on my index.php (the page that includes my functions.php) : $app = new `gator();
$app->init();`

Comment: @apatik - per Dan, in regards to `static` methods/functions; Static methods are declared as such: `public static function myFunctionName() {}`

Comment: @axiac very cool suggestion, I reported the errors in my post (see update) it looks like you're right.

Comment: The answer is in the errors you've posted, as dan08 pointed out.  You're mixing static and non-static methods incorrectly.  When you called `checkPrivileges()` in a static context, you got a warning, and then an error inside that method because `$this` is null in a static context.

Comment: Ryan Vincent : hum I can't remember why I made it this way but it used to work with this :/ I'll do some test with your suggestion tho, but still, it should return something anyways right ? This may be something I'll have te change when this problem is fixed. Thanks

Comment: Allright I'm starting to understand, so I should either declare checkPrivileges as a static method or call it non-statically ? edit : well I changed it to `public static function checkPrivileges($getprivileges)` and the error is gone. The error on "line 97" still stands tho. Thanks for the help by the way !

Comment: After a lot of researches and thanks to your suggestions I think I've been able to fix this, I'm testing it out, updating this later to confirm and share the solution

Comment: Until you really understand the difference, you should start off just not writing any static methods.  Instantiate your class with `$somevar = new myClass(...);`, and call methods on it with `->` and not `::`.  Eventually you'll *need* a static method, and you'll know it.  Before then, you don't.